# eclipse javafx variables unresolved

Tags: linux, eclipse, javafx

When I create a new javaFX project the javaFX variables are unresolved. I use java 8 (121) and eclipse Neon on which I installed e(fx)clipse. OS is Linux Mint 18.1. What I did:

- I uninstalled and installed e(fx)clipse again, that didn't help
- In another post I read that someone had solved the problem by adding
  jfxrt.jar to the build path. I searched for this file but it is not present on my file system

Anybody any idea what is wrong in my setup?

**Edit**

James_D suggested adding openjfx. I read documentation of openjfx and it says that only a subset is implemented. I decided to install the oracle JDK and adjust the building path with a reference to the oracle version of jfxrt. That worked. I wonder whether it wouldn't be better to switch to the oracle version of JDK?

Comment: You probably have OpenJDK, which does not include JavaFX. You will (I think) need to install [OpenJFX](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main). The Oracle JDK comes with JavaFX included, but I don't know if it works on Linux Mint ([supported platforms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) include RHEL, Suse, and Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks, I'll start experimenting. I'll be back with the results of that.

Comment: @James_D - Your answer put me on the right track though I did something slightly different, see the Edit. If you make it an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Oracle bundles Java and JavaFX with their installers, it was split before JDK 8 into separate packages. As OpenJFX IS required for launching JavaFX-applications using OpenJDK, you might want to add that into your installation-documentation. It IS cross-platform.

Comment: It was this sentence: "OpenJFX is presently a subset of JavaFX", found on http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/getting-started.html which made me decide to switch to a full oracle java setup. I have removed the remark about cross platform development.